# Truncate PHP string with a specific delimiter

Tags: php, function

Good morning,

I need to truncate a string with a specific delimiter character.
For example with that string:

```
myString = 'customname_489494984';
```

I would like to strip automatically every string parts after "_" 
(in this case "489494984").

Is there a function in order to truncate the string part after a specific 
delimiter?

Many thanks!

François

Answer (score 3):

You can also use strstr() which finds the first occurrence of a string:

```
$myString= "customname_489494984";
echo strstr($myString, '_', true);
```

Here's my reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

Comment: This is the best answer. Add a link to the PHP doc for strstr() & it's perfect.

Comment: @mopo922, I've edited my answer and added my reference link. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple combo of [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

```
$myString = 'customname_489494984';
echo substr($myString, 0, strpos($myString, '_'));
```

**BONUS -** Wrap it in a custom function:

```
function truncateStringAfter($string, $delim)
{
    return substr($string, 0, strpos($string, $delim));
}
echo truncateStringAfter('customname_489494984', '_');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,It will remove anything after "_".

```
$string= 'customname_489494984';
$string=substr($string, 0, strrpos($string, '_'));
```

Comment: Afer **-** or **_** ? :)

Comment: Okay. I was just saying. I know it was a typing mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with other straightforward approaches is that if the String doesn't contain “_” then an empty String will be returned. Here is a small StringUtils class (part of a larger one) that does that with beforeFirst static method in a multibyte safe way.

```
var_dump(StringUtils::beforeFirst("customname_489494984", "_"));
class StringUtils
{
  /**
   * Returns the part of a string <b>before the first</b> occurrence of the string to search for.
   * @param <b>$string</b> The string to be searched
   * @param <b>$search</b> The string to search for
   * @param <b>$caseSensitive boolean :optional</b> Defines if the search will be case sensitive. By default true.
   * @return string
   */
  public static function beforeFirst($string,$search,$caseSensitive = true)
  {
    $firstIndex = self::firstIndexOf($string, $search,$caseSensitive);
    return $firstIndex == 0 ? $string : self::substring($string, 0 , $firstIndex);
  }


  /**
   * Returns a part of the string from a character and for as many characters as provided
   * @param <b>$string</b> The string to retrieve the part from
   * @param <b>$start</b> The index of the first character (0 for the first one)
   * @param <b>$length</b> The length of the part the will be extracted from the string
   * @return string
   */
  public static function substring($string,$start,$length = null)
  {
    return ( $length == null ) ? ( mb_substr($string, $start) ) : ( $length == 0 ? "" : mb_substr($string, $start , $length) );
  }

  /**
   * Return the index of <b>the first occurance</b> of a part of a string to the string
   * @param <b>$string</b> The string to be searched
   * @param <b>$search</b> The string to search for
   * @param <b>$caseSensitive boolean :optional</b> Defines if the search will be case sensitive. By default true.
   * @return number
   */
  public static function firstIndexOf($string,$search,$caseSensitive = true)
  {
    return $caseSensitive ? mb_strpos($string, $search) : mb_stripos($string, $search);
  }  

    /**
   * Returns how many characters the string is
   * @param <b>$string</b> The string
   * @return number
   */
  public static function length($string)
  {
    return mb_strlen($string);
  }

}
```